# Ansible mount for different directories on different servers

Tags: ansible, mount-point

we have different mount points configured in `/etc/fstab` file for different servers. How can i achieve the same using Ansible?

**For example:**

server A has a **source** `node1:/data/col1/RMAN` mounted at **path** `/mountPointA`

Above can we achieved using Ansible's mount module such as

---

```
- name: Add Mount Points
mount:
  path: /mnt/dvd
  src : /dev/sr0
  fstype: iso09660
  opts: ro
  boot: yes
  state: present
```

> **BUT**

What if i have another **server "B"** which has **source** `/node1:/data/col1/directoryB` needs to be mounted at **path** /`mountPointB`. However this server does not need the first mount point to be configured.

Is it possible to achieve it in single yml file?

**In other words**

```
Host      source                   dest

hostA    /source/directoryA     /mnt

hostB    /source/directoryB     /mnt or /mnt/subdirectory #assuming subdir exists
```

i hope this make sense. sorry for the confusion. This playbook will be run on bulk of hosts, how do i make sure the right host is automatically selected to be using the right mount points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to approach this.  I'm going to suggest an approach that would let you defined multiple mountpoints per host, if you so desired.  If you have a `host_vars` directory in the same place as your playbook, Ansible will look there for files named after your hosts and load variables from those files.  For example, if you have a host in your inventory named `serverA`, Ansible would look for `host_vars/serverA.yml`.

We're going to take advantage of that to specify per-host mount configurations.  Create a file `host_vars/serverA.yml` containing:

```
mountinfo:
  - src: node1:/data/col1/RMAN
    dst: /mountpointA
    fstype: nfs
```

And create `host_vars/serverB.yml` with:

```
mountinfo:
  - src: node1:/data/col1/directoryB
    dst: /mountpointB
    fstype: nfs
```

And then in your playbook:

```
- name: Add Mount Points
  mount:
    path: "{{ item.dst }}"
    src : "{{ item.src }}"
    fstype: "{{ item.fstype }}"
    opts: ro
    boot: yes
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ mountinfo }}"
  when: mountinfo is defined
```

In case something in this answer wasn't clear I've wrapped up the above as a runnable example [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-46492417).